# Using Service Bus to access On Premise WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, servicebus

I want to connect an On-Premise `WCF Service` with `Service Bus`. In all tutorials I referred, they are creating the service and hooking it up with Service Bus. Can we hook up an On-Premise WCF service with `Service Bus` **if we just know the end point address of WCF Service**?

I don't have access to the code of the service.

Comment: Do you mean like what is explained over here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/ ?
The solution in the article allows to create a wcf service that is hosted on premise and having its endpoint published using the azure service bus. Therefore it can be accessed from anywhere. Im just not entirely sure if this is what you want.

Comment: No, the service is already hosted on remote machine for which we don't have access. I want to know whether we can call that service with service bus.

Comment: Is the "remote machine" hosting the WCF service part of your on-premises environment or someone else's environment?

Comment: Hi @RickRainey, it's part of our on-premises environment.